# chrome not displaying images in dynamically created new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window

I am creating a new window using javascript and displaying images present on the server. The window opens fine and displays the images on Firefox but not on Chrome. What could be wrong?

```
function wopen(){
nwin = window.open('','_blank','directories=no,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,width=800,top=10,left=60');
nwin.document.open();
var msg = "<html><head><title>Test page</title></head><body><img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/images/logo.jpg' border='0' height='20' width='20'></body></html>"
nwin.document.write(msg);
nwin.document.close();
}
```

When I am calling this function, the window opens but the image is not displayed in chrome, but is displayed correctly in Firefox. What is the problem here?

Comment: Maybe because there is no closing _</html>_ tag in msg?

Comment: As much as possible , please avoid using document.write

Comment: With your code and img link I got the same result. Nothing. Opening image link directly in browser it redirected me to _http://website.1and1.com/_

Using the same code with my local jpg file: image was opened in popup window.

Comment: Do you have access to your specific jpg file?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic, mywebsite.com is fake url; it doesn't exist. I was giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved after I changed a setting in my web hosting server; all I did was to cancel the image hotlinking, which was previously active.